# Trouble on translating views after renaming statements from 'translate' to 'I18n.t' and from 'localize' to 'I18n.l'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, i18n-gem

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I have a strange problem. In my view files I use the following code:

```
# app/views/articles/show.html.erb
I18n.t('.page_title')
```

When I render the above view code in the browser I get the `translation missing: en.page_title` message. However, as you can see from the "missing" message, the translation doesn't refer to the `articles.show.page_title` YML statement... but it should do that! It seems that the [“Lazy” Lookup](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations) doesn't work as expected.

*Why that happens? Have you some idea about the issue and how to solve it?*

Note: I just made a code refactoring renaming statements from `translate` to `I18n.t` and from `localize` to `I18n.l`...

Comment: Why is there a dot in *.page_title*? Also, I don't know why would Rails look for *articles.show.page_title* while you only specified *page_title*.

Comment: @Samy Dindane - It's [“Lazy” Lookup](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations) (see the 4.1.4 paragraph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply: `t('.page_title')` Then you should see another statement. But in fact, I18n searches in several places. You can add the translation and see for yourself:

```
en:
  page-title:
```

Or:

```
en:
  articles:
    show:
      page-title:
```

Comment: OK, it works by using `t('.page_title')`. But, I am very curious, *why the `I18n.t('.page_title')` statement doesn't work in view files?*

Comment: I think that's why: "Second, it’ll scope the key by the current partial if the key starts with a period. So if you call translate(".foo") from the people/index.html.erb template, you’ll actually be calling I18n.translate("people.index.foo")." From the translation helper method documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-translate

Comment: I18n library itself does not expand a dot, but the helper method #t in views does and calls I18n.t with the full translation key.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately RailsGuides not mention about this.